# Blazor onchange in paragraph

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

In Blazor with the EventCallback you can run a function in a parent component when something changes in a child component. In the sample below the child component is waiting for button click and on that click the parent component runs the needed function (parent component not presented).

Is there a way to similarly run the function from the parent component if something changes inside the paragraph?

```
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button @onclick="OnChangeEvent" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnChangeEvent { get; set; }
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to handle the event locally *and* raise it to the parent perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button @onclick="OnChangeEvent" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
```

This code will never work. You can't use the @onclick directive twice. You can do something like this instead:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>


private void IncrementCount()
{
        currentCount++;

        OnChangeEvent.InvokeAsync();
}
```

> Is there a way to similarly run the function from the parent component if something changes inside the paragraph?

What is paragraph? Do you mean the `<p>` element ?

If yes, then you also mean running the function from the parent component when currentCount changes, right ? In that case, my sample above do the very thing...increment currentCount and then call the function. You may also pass a value to the function.